# How to change libwebsockets color scheme

Tags: libwebsockets

I am using libwebsockets library. This exposes certain methods for writing into a log file.
`lwsl_warn(...)`, `lwsl_err(...)` and `lwsl_err(...)`
to name the most common.
The output is color coded using ANSI sequences.

Is there a way to set the default color scheme (other than recompiling the library)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I poked around in the libwebsockets source and found my answer:
The colors are hard coded - so the answer to my original question is "no".

However, the color scheme is not hard to find and edit. It resides in two source files - one of these is compiled depending on options:

```
libwebsockets/lib/core/logs.c
```

and

```
libwebsockets/lib/plat/optee/lws-plat-optee.c
```

All it takes is to edit the self-explanatory table:

```
static const char * const colours[] = {
    "[31;1m", /* LLL_ERR */
    "[36;1m", /* LLL_WARN */
    "[35;1m", /* LLL_NOTICE */ 
    "[32;1m", /* LLL_INFO */
    "[34;1m", /* LLL_DEBUG */
    "[33;1m", /* LLL_PARSER */
    "[33m",   /* LLL_HEADER */
    "[33m",   /* LLL_EXT */
    "[33m",   /* LLL_CLIENT */
    "[33;1m", /* LLL_LATENCY */
    "[0;1m",  /* LLL_USER */
    "[31m",   /* LLL_THREAD */
};
```

Then build as before. Once in the `libwebsockets/build` directory do the following:

```
make clean
make && sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

... and enjoy!